# Argument of type 'PassportStatic' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Passport'. Types of property 'use' are incompatible

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to implement a login feature in my app for which I'm using passport for authentication. But I'm getting error on typescript compilation:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
server/server.ts (132,26): Argument of type 'PassportStatic' is not         
assignable to parameter of type 'Passport'.
Types of property 'use' are incompatible.
Type '{ (strategy: Strategy): PassportStatic; (name: string, strategy: Strategy): PassportStatic; }' is not assignable to type '{ (strategy: Strategy): this; (name: string, strategy: Strategy): this; }'.
  Type 'PassportStatic' is not assignable to type 'this'. (2345)
at getOutput (/media/rohan/1084CB1284CAF96C/code/hall3/hall3-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307:15)
at /media/rohan/1084CB1284CAF96C/code/hall3/hall3-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:336:16
at Object.compile (/media/rohan/1084CB1284CAF96C/code/hall3/hall3-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:496:11)
at Module.m._compile (/media/rohan/1084CB1284CAF96C/code/hall3/hall3-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:392:43)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/media/rohan/1084CB1284CAF96C/code/hall3/hall3-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:12)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
```

Here's my code for server.ts :

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import * as httpLogger from 'morgan';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as path from 'path';

// Config
import { Config } from './config/local';
import { PassportConfig } from './config/passport';
import { logger } from './config/logger';

/**
 * The server.
 *
 * @class Server
 */
export class Server {

  // The express app instance
  public app: express.Application;

  /**
   * Bootstrap the application
   *
   * @class Server
   * @method bootstrap
   * @static
   * @return {ng.auto.IInjectorService} Returns the newly created injector for this app
   */
  public static bootstrap = (): Server => {
    return new Server();
  };

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @class Server
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor() {

    // create expressjs application
    this.app = express();

    // configure application
    this.config();
    this.routes();

  }

  /**
   * Configure application
   *
   * @class Server
   * @method config
   */
  public config = (): void => {

    this.app.use(httpLogger('dev'));

    // use json bodyparser
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // use query string parser
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));

    // use CookieParser for setting and reading cookies
    this.app.use(cookieParser(Config.session_secret));

   /* some code skipped */

    // Set up passport
    **PassportConfig.setup(passport, this.userModel);**
    this.app.use(passport.initialize());
    this.app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

  }

  /**
   * Create router
   *
   * @class Server
   * @method routes
   */
  public routes = () => {

    // Backend Admin API Routes
    let prefix = '';
    //this.app.use(`/accounts`, LoginRoute.create(this.model.localUser, passport));
    this.app.use('/data', DataRoute.create());
    this.app.use('/files', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')));

  };

  /**
   * Shutdown
   *
   * @class Server
   * @method shutdown
   */
  public shutdown = () => {
    logger.info('Shutting Down');
    this.connection.close();
  }

}
```

And here's my code for PassportConfig :

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Passport } from 'passport';
import { Strategy, IStrategyOptions, VerifyFunction } from 'passport-local';

import { IUserModel } from '../models/user';

export class PassportConfig {

  static setup = (passport: Passport, model: Model<IUserModel>) => {

    // serialize by username as it is unique <Type of user, type of id>
    passport.serializeUser<IUserModel, string>((user: IUserModel, done) => {
      // Return unique identification of the user
      done(null, user._id);
    });

    // deserialize by username <Type of user, typeof of id>
    passport.deserializeUser<IUserModel, string>((id: string, done) => {
      // findbyid and return user
      model.findById(id, (err, user: IUserModel) => {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    // Specify strategy options
    let options: IStrategyOptions = {
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: false
    };

    // verify function for signup
    let verifySignUp: VerifyFunction = (username: string, password: string, done) => {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        model.findOne({
          'username': username
        }, (err, user: IUserModel) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          if (user) {
            return done(err, null);
          } else {
            let newUser = new model();
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
            // save the user
            newUser.save((error) => {
              return done(error, newUser);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    };

    let verifySignIn: VerifyFunction = (username: string, password: string, done) => {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        model.findOne({
          'username': username
        }, (err, user: IUserModel) => {
          if (err)
            return done(err);
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, null);
          } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, null);
          }
          return done(null, user);
        });
      });
    };

    passport.use('local-signup', new Strategy(options, verifySignUp));
    passport.use('local-signin', new Strategy(options, verifySignIn));

  }
}
```

My Webstorm IDE gives a red underline under `passport` on the line `PassportConfig.setup(passport, this.userModel);` in my server.ts file.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing based just on imports, but it looks like you are importing everything from `passport` library in `server.ts`:

`import * as passport from 'passport';`

And so variable `passport` is of type `PassportStatic`.

And in `PassportConfig` you're importing concrete exported class `Passport` from library `passport`:

`import { Passport } from 'passport';`

So variable `Passport` is of type `Passport`.

To fix this you can do several things:

1. Import `Passport` in `server.ts` the same way as in `PassportConfig`
2. Use `passport.Passport` in `server.ts` (instead of just `Passport`)